# Is react native a hybrid web app library?

Tags: cordova, react-native

Is react native a kind of cordova library as a hybrid webview library or does it really use the native components of operating system?

Comment: React Native uses the native components of the OS. For an example of how to do this check out the example here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-ios.html#content

Answer (score 0):

React Native is not hybrid like Cordoba but uses native IOS, Android, or UWP OS to render elements.  For example a View renders as UIView or Widget.View or whatever it is called in UWP.

Currently, I see very little examples outthere for UWP but good place for your to start is reading

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/

http://www.reactnativeexpress.com/listview

That will clarify it a lot